# How to dry code?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, view, dry

I am working with has many through association in Application.
I access email from employee table in INDEX action of InventoryController like below code:

```
<% @inventories.each do |inventory| %>
    <% inventory.employee_inventories.each do |e| %>
            <%if e[:status]== 'ALLOTED'%>
                  <%= e.employee.email%>
             <% end %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Please help me How to DRY this code in view? Thanks in advance

Comment: May be you can add a `scope` to the respective model which queries the `status == 'ALLOTED'` records and use that scope in this view.

Answer (score 0):

```
@alloted_emails = @inventories.flat_map(&:employee_inventories).select do |i|
  i[:status] == 'ALLOTED'
end.map do |i|
  i.employee.email
end
```

Unless you want to create a scope as suggested by @Pavan, just introduce this var and use it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the same code in different views then you can create a helper.

Otherwise write down this code like-

```
<% @inventories.each do |inventory| %>
  <% inventory.employee_inventories.each do |e| %>
      <%= e.employee.email if e[:status]== 'ALLOTED' %>     
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The main problem in your code is n+1 query problem. If you are using eager  loading then there is no issue otherwise use eager loading using includes keyword in your query.